# ssrs reporting services Excel render on single sheet

Tags: xml, excel, reporting-services

I have a report that has a fair amount of columns providing a comparison of sales year over year in counts and revenue.  I do not have page breaks set anywhere I can find, however, when the report renders in Visual Studio or in the web browser, I get the columns for a single year on each sheet.

I went into the XML and there are no page break tags, yet the behavior persists.  Can anyone suggest some other feature that might produce this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of places to check:

1. Right click on your tablix and choose Tablix Properties. Take a look at the page break options on the General tab and ensure none are checked.
2. Click on your row/column groups and select Group Properties for each. Ensure nothing is checked on the Page Breaks tab.
3. Go to the Properties window and select Report. Set the page size for height and width to 0.